# Changing colors in Mayavi plot3d function by given range

Tags: python, visualization, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have a data frame with 4 columns x,y,z, and magnitude(value that need to be plotted) the magnitude value varies from 0 to 30.3. I need to plot the surface if the maximum and minimum magnitude is given to me. Let say I have been given minimum magnitude to be 2.0 and maximum magnitude to be 10.0. So I want to plot it in such a way that the values larger than the maximum value should stand out in red color and the values less than minimum value should stand out in green color.

The below code I tried but I am getting all green color plot.

```
p7 = mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Magnitude_F'],tube_radius=Config.BEADDIAMETER, tube_sides=Config.BEADCORNERS, colormap='copper',vmin = 2, vmax = 10.0)
p8 = mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Magnitude_F'],tube_radius=Config.BEADDIAMETER, tube_sides=Config.BEADCORNERS, color=(1,0,0),vmin = 10.0)
p9 = mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Magnitude_F'],tube_radius=Config.BEADDIAMETER, tube_sides=Config.BEADCORNERS, color=(0,1,0),vmax = 2.0)

mlab.colorbar(object=p7, title="Points in Magnitude_F") 
mlab.colorbar(object=p8, title="Above maximum Magnitude_F",orientation = 'vertical' )
mlab.colorbar(object = p9, title= "Below minimum Magnitude_F", orientation = 'vertical')

mlab.show()
```

The below image is I am getting when I use the below code.
Now on this, I just want that If I set a maximum value as 10 then all the value above 10 i.e 10 to 27.1 should be represented with single color that can be highlighted as I am not comfortable with that high value. Similar with lower value as well if I set 2 as lower value then all values below 2 should be of a single color. In the bleow image its dificult for me to see the values above 10 as its dificult to read.

```
p7 = mlab.plot3d(df['x_coordinate'],df['y_coordinate'],df['z_coordinate'],df['Magnitude_F'],tube_radius=Config.BEADDIAMETER, tube_sides=Config.BEADCORNERS, colormap='blue-red')
mlab.colorbar(object=p7, title="Magnitude_F")
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzVyw.jpg)

Comment: normally, separating magnitudes is done by [using contours and isosurfaces](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_contour_contour.html#example-contour-contour). Would that help?

Comment: @FelipeLema I just need to change the color value of certain limits so that I can detect the highs and lows easily so like whenever the value goes above let suppose 10 then it should show it with red. I used color map but it develops color taking all the values. That's why in the code above I tried using vmax and vmin. But it overlaps the points3d function return before.

Comment: you should add an [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand your problem better

Comment: @FelipeLema I have made some edits to the post. Can you help me with this?